# taffydb javascript object value from variable

Tags: javascript, taffydb

I have the folllowing TaffyDB database:

```
var entities = TAFFY([{id:"0",name:"name1",pos_x:"200",pos_y:"200"},{id:"1",name:"name2",pos_x:"200",pos_y:"400"}]);
```

and would like to loop through picking up the x_pos of each database row in a variable.

This is what I got so far:

```
var entities_ID_array = Array();
entities_ID_array = entities().select("id");

for(i=0; i<entities_ID_array.length; i++){

        var pos_x = entities({id:i}).select("pos_x");
        alert(pos_x);

}
```

The alert gives empty results. If I change `{id:i}` to `{id:0}` and `{id:1}` is picks up the corresponding pos_x. Hence the difficulty I'm having seems to be the fact that I want to refer to a variable. The [i] notation doesn't seem to help either.

Who can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't declare your variable i = I've edited it for you below:

var entities = TAFFY([{id:"0",name:"name1",pos_x:"200",pos_y:"200"},{id:"1",name:"name2",pos_x:"200",pos_y:"400"}]);
and would like to loop through picking up the x_pos of each database row in a variable.

This is what I got so far:

var entities_ID_array = Array();
entities_ID_array = entities().select("id");

for(var i=0; i

```
    var pos_x = entities({id:i}).select("pos_x");
    alert(pos_x);
```

}

Comment: To make your post easier to read you can format you code.  You can do this by using 4 spaces initially and 4 spaces afterwards per indent